# haskell type,new type or data for only an upper case char

Tags: haskell

If i want to make a String but holds only an uppercase character. I know that String is a [Char]. I have tried something like `type a = ['A'..'Z']` but it did not work any help?

Answer (score 7):

What you're wanting is dependent types, which Haskell doesn't have.  Dependent types are those that *depend* on values, so using dependent types you could encode at the type level a vector with length 5 as

```
only5 :: Vector 5 a -> Vector 10 a
only5 vec = concatenate vec vec
```

Again, Haskell does not have dependent types, but languages like Agda, Coq and Idris do support them.  Instead, you could just use a "smart constructor"

```
module MyModule
    ( Upper      -- export type only, not constructor
    , mkUpper    -- export the smart constructor
    ) where

import Data.Char (isUpper)

newtype Upper = Upper String deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Ord)

mkUpper :: String -> Maybe Upper
mkUpper s = if all isUpper s then Just (Upper s) else Nothing
```

Here the constructor `Upper` is not exported, just the type, and then users of this module have to use the `mkUpper` function that safely rejects non-uppercase strings.

---

For clarification, and to show how awesome dependent types can be, consider the mysterious `concatenate` function from above.  If I were to define this with dependent types, it would actually look something like

```
concatenate :: Vector n a -> Vector m a -> Vector (n + m) a
concatenate v1 v2 = undefined
```

Wait, what's arithmetic doing in a type signature?  It's actually performing type-system level computations on the values that this type is dependent on.  This removes a lot of potential boilerplate in Haskell, and it makes guarantees at compilation time that, e.g., arrays can't have negative length.

Comment: Which in practice is as if having dependent types :)

Comment: Great answer (as usual)!

Answer (score 2):

Most desires for dependent types can be filled either using smart constructors (see bheklilr's answer), generating Haskell from an external tool (Coq, Isabelle, Inch, etc), or using an exact representation.  You probably want the first solution.

To exactly represent just the capitals then you could write a data type that includes a constructor for each letter and conversion to/from strings:

```
data Capital = CA | CB | CC | CD | CE | CF | CG | CH | CI | CJ | CK | CL | CM | CN | CO | CP | CQ | CR | CS | CT | CU | CV | CW | CX | CY | CZ deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)


toString :: [Capital] -> String
toString = map (toEnum . (+ (fromEnum 'A')) . fromEnum)
```

You can even go a step further and allow conversion from string literals, `"Anything in quotes"`, to a type `[Capitals]` by using the `OverloadedStrings` extension.  Just add to the top of your file `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, FlexibleInstances #-}`, be sure to `import Data.String` and write the instance:

```
type Capitals = [Capital]

instance IsString Capitals where
    fromString = map (toEnum . (subtract (fromEnum 'A')) . fromEnum) . filter (\x -> 'A' <= x && x <= 'Z')
```

After that, you can type capitals all you want!

```
*Main> toString ("jfoeaFJOEW" :: Capitals)
"FJOEW"
*Main>
```

Answer (score 1):

bheklilr is correct but perhaps for your purposes the following could be OK:

```
import Data.Char(toUpper)

newtype UpperChar = UpperChar Char
deriving (Show)

upperchar :: Char -> UpperChar
upperchar = UpperChar. toUpper
```

You can alternatively make UpperChar an alias of Char (use type instead of newtype) which would allow you to forms lists of both Char and UpperChar. The problem with an alias, however, is that you could feed a Char into a function expecting an UpperChar...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do something similar which will work well for the Latin script of your choice but not so well as a fully general solution is to use a custom type to represent upper case letters. Something like this should do the trick:

```
data UpperChar = A|B|C|D| (fill in the rest) | Y | Z deriving (Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)

newtype UpperString = UpperString [UpperChar]

instance Show UpperString
    show (UpperString s) = map show s
```

The members of this type are not Haskell `String`s, but you can convert between them as needed.